# Simple way to output list in the style "V, W, X, Y, and Z" in R

Tags: string, r, formatting, r-markdown

When using `rmarkdown` it is frequently the case that you want to programmatically generate fragments of text, in particular to list items being used.  For example;

```
The species of iris examined were `r cat(as.character(unique(iris$Species)), sep = ", ")`.
```

Which would produce

> The species of iris examined were setosa, versicolor, virginica.

To read properly it should be

> The species of iris examined were setosa, versicolor, and virginica.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Maybe try retrieving your values beforehand and then using your current formatting for all but the last value and then concatenate that with an "and" and the final value of your list?

Comment: Yeah - making a function to do this would't be too hard.  You could even have an oxford.comma parameter.  That should clearly default to true ;)

Comment: why would one not use an oxford comma? "setosa, veriscolor and virginica" imply that versicolor and virginica are both setosa which is probably not what you want

Comment: Added oxford comma.  Happy now?  :-)

Comment: not until there is peace on earth

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one of the helpful tools in the [pander](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander) package

[pander::p](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/blob/master/R/helpers.R#L39%3aL89)

> p merges elements of a vector in one string for the sake of pretty inline printing. Default parameters are read from appropriate option values (see argument description for details). This function allows you to put the results of an expression that yields a variable inline, by wrapping the vector elements with the string provided in **wrap**, and separating elements by main and ending separator (**sep** and **copula**). In case of a two-length vector, value specified in copula will be used as a separator. You can also control the length of provided vector by altering an integer value specified in **limit** argument (defaults to Inf).

example:

```
devtools::install_github('Rapporter/pander')
## also available on cran:
# install.packages('pander')

library(pander)

p(levels(iris$Species), wrap = '')
# "setosa, versicolor and virginica"

p(levels(iris$Species), wrap = '', copula = ', and ')
# "setosa, versicolor, and virginica"
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's such a function

```
wordlist<-function(w, oxford=F) {
    if(length(w)==1) return(w);
    if(length(w)==2) return(paste(w[1],"and",w[2]));
    paste0( paste(w[-length(w)], collapse=", "), 
        ifelse(oxford,",","")," and ", w[length(w)] )
}

wordlist(unique(iris$Species))
# [1] "setosa, versicolor and virginica"
```

(with oxford set to false per the OP's example)

Comment: @rawr that p function looks like exactly what I was after - can you make it an answer?  While this is good (+1), I would prefer to accept pander::p - learning about the existence of pander::p is more valuable than a one off solution.

Answer (score 4):

Recursive function to handle the final two elements differently:

```
wordlist <- function(w) { 
                          if (length(w) <= 2) {
                            paste(w, collapse=' and ') # Or collapse=', and '
                          } else {
                            paste(w[1], Recall(w[-1]), sep=', ')
                          }
                        }
wordlist(LETTERS[1:6])
## [1] "A, B, C, D, E and F"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
toStringAnd <- function(s) {
    n <- length(s)
    if (n < 2) s else toString(s[-n], paste("and", s[n]))
}

# test
toStringAnd( tail(LETTERS) )
## [1] "U, V, W, X, Y, and Z"
```

**Note:** The above answers the question but just in case you change your mind and decide not to have a comma before the `and` then:

```
toStringAnd2 <- function(s) {
    n <- length(s)
    if (n < 2) s else paste(toString(s[-n]), "and", s[n])
}

# test
toStringAnd2( tail(LETTERS) )
## [1] "U, V, W, X, Y and Z"
```

Other variations are possible depending on what you want such as not using a comma if there are only two input components and using a comma if there are more than two but the general pattern of combining `toString` and `paste` should be clear at this point.

**Update** Added Note and some improvements.